# Declare variable in one line if statement

Tags: c#

I wonder why this syntax is not allowed in c#?

```
var email = (User user = User.Current) != null ? user.Email : "default@mail.com";
```

When this is allowed:

```
User user;
var email = (user = User.Current) != null ? user.Email : "default@mail.com";
```

Why does the variable have to be defined already, and cannot be defined in the statement?

This would help to make lines shorter, for example:

```
var email = User.Current.Very.Complex.Path != null ? User.Current.Very.Complex.Path.Email : "default@mail.com";
```

could be

```
var email = (var user = User.Current.Very.Complex.Path) != null ? user.Email : "default@mail.com";
```

Comment: This is due to the scope/encapsulation. If you declare the variable in the ternary, it's only available within it and I suspect the compiler guesses this is a fault. Also, some times, having a few more lines is better than 1 if it improves readability. Personally, I'd rather this split over a few lines, but each to their own here!

Comment: Is () a scope? I thought this could work like `a` can be used in `using(var a = GetVar()){ /*use a*/}`. Ie: variables declared in one line if's can be used in the rest of the statement.

Comment: Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559274/why-cant-we-define-a-variable-inside-an-if-statement)

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault Ah, this seems like the answer!

Comment: IMHO doing that would decrease readability, why don't you want to just do the 2nd block? Your final example could just be turned in to `User user; var email = (user = User.Current.Very.Complex.Path) != null ? user.Email : "default@mail.com";`

Comment: I can't see it at the moment, but it seems like the null-coalescing operator (??) should be able to help you out here. Maybe you need a default user instance somewhere.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Unfortunately not without having to constructing a new User: `var email = (User.Current ?? new User { Email = "default@mail.com" }).Email;`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, apparently the c# team disagrees. `Declaration Expressions` almost made it into c# 6.0 and will make it into a future release sooner or later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not allowed, per the C# specification. This is basically because a variable declaration/initialization is a statement, not an expression (see [Why can't we define a variable inside an if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559274/why-cant-we-define-a-variable-inside-an-if-statement) for more details; credit to [Pierre-Luc Pineault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467203/declare-variable-in-one-line-if-statement/18467482#comment27141630_18467203) for linking that).

Here is another way to do it, which I think has high readability and conciseness:

```
var user = User.Current.Very.Complex.Path;
var email = user != null ? user.Email : "default@mail.com";
```