# Is there a C# equivalent to the Python := (an assignment expression)?

Tags: python, c#, expression, assignment-operator

[Assignment expression Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions)

I like how it saves line. Example:

```
for rule in rules:
    place = getPlace(rule)
    if place:
        print(f"Apply rule {rule.__name__} -> {place}")
        return place
raise Exception('No rule found!')
```

↓↓

```
for rule in rules:
    if place:= getPlace(rule):
        print(f"Apply rule {rule.__name__} -> {place}")
        return place
raise Exception('No rule found!')
```

Is there a C# equivalent or it needs to use variable assignment on the line before?

Comment: Not really. The following question asks the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467203/declare-variable-in-one-line-if-statement# In this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559274/why-cant-we-define-a-variable-inside-an-if-statement?noredirect=1&lq=1 Rand.Function shows a clever way, but that shouldn't be used since it is confusing.

Comment: When _writing_ in C#, why do you _think_ in Python? What does your C# code look like in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there isn't a perfect 1:1 match, but in your case you could use

```cs
foreach (var rule in rules)
{
    string place;
    if ((place = GetPlace(rule)) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Found {place}");
        return place;
    }
}
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y9jXKm) is a demo. The `((place = GetPlace(rule)) != null)` is only used very rarely in C#, a more idiomatic way would be to make the `GetPlace` return a bool indicating success and a `out` parameter like so (naming convention would also tell us to name this method `TryGetPlace`)

```
public bool TryGetPlace(string rule, out string place)
```

Setting `place` to a value and returning `true` if successful, and returning `false` if not, you'd then use it like so:

```cs
foreach (var rule in rules)
{
    if (TryGetPlace(rule, out var place))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Found {place}");
        return place;
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not "obscure" because assignment is already an expression in C# (and also C, C++ and many other C-like languages). It's extremely common in C to use things like `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)`

Comment: You could also use the `bool GetPlace( string rule, out string place )` "pattern" ...

Comment: @phuclv I classified this as obscure in C# since you almost never see it in C#, maybe "is rarely used in C#" is more accurate

Comment: @Fildor I agree, while this is closer to the Python code OP has written up, the idiomatic C# way would (IMO) be `bool TryGetPlace(string rule, out string place)`