# Initializing and testing an object inside an if expression to reduce it's lifespan

Tags: c#

I'm wondering if I can initialize an object inside an object inside the test expression of an `if` statement and test whether or not it's null there.

Trying it like this gives a syntax error.

```
public void test()
{
   if ((ArtItem artItem=_context.ArtItems.FirstOrDefault(ai=>ai.Id==1)) != null)
   {

   }
}
```

Also, if such a thing were possible, would it be more efficient than doing this?

```
public void test()
{
    ArtItem artItem = _context.ArtItems.FirstOrDefault(ai => ai.Id == 1);
            if (artItem != null)
    {

    }
}
```

I assume yes, since it would technically be initialized and destroyed within the scope of the if statement, not the entire function.

[image]

Comment: In recent versions of C#, you can use the `is` operator like this: `if(... is ArtItem artItem)`

Comment: It will be "destroyed" whenever the garbage collector feels like it, which is entirely non-deterministic. Why do you care? I'd put money on there being no measurable difference between the two.

Comment: `if(_context.ArtItems.FirstOrDefault(ai=>ai.Id==1)) != null)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559274/why-cant-we-define-a-variable-inside-an-if-statement

Comment: I'm getting errors, @JayakumarThangavel, the following : 'ArtItem' is a type, which is not valid in the given context, `The name `artItem` does not exist in the current context`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. <s>You cannot: [Why can't we define a variable inside an if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559274/why-cant-we-define-a-variable-inside-an-if-statement)</s>

   You can in C#7.0 with [**pattern variables**](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/new-features-in-c-7-0/): `if (o is int i || (o is string s && int.TryParse(s, out i)) { /* use i */ }`
2. `var x = ...; if(x != null)` is still the usual way to go.

---

> I assume yes, since it would technically be initialized and destroyed within the scope of the if statement, not the entire function.

It will only be garbage collected when the garbage collection runs, which may be long after your method finished, and maybe even not in the first the GC runs. Under normal circumstances you should not worry about this.

---

Update

Here is an example with `FirstOrDefault` and `!= null` check.

```
class A
    {
        public string P1 { get; set; } = "Hello!";
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        M1(new List<A>(){new A()});
        M1(new List<A>());
    }

    static void M1(List<A> l)
    {
        if(l.FirstOrDefault(a => a != null) is var x && x != null) {
                Console.WriteLine(x.P1);
        }
        else {
                Console.WriteLine("null");
        }
    }
```

```
Hello!
null
```